# Cancel Button During Countdown

Tags: java, android, button, countdown

Quick question here, I have the following code working for the most part, but I would like for the button to go back to it's original state if it is clicked during the countdown. Any suggestions?

```
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        button.setText("SENT");                 

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long sec) {
                        button.setText("CANCEL (" + sec / 1000 + ")");
                        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                cancel();

                            }

                        });

                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
```

Before the button is ever pressed, it will say "Push Me." Once pressed, the countdown will begin and the button's text will change each second (CANCEL (3), CANCEL (2), CANCEL (1)) and after the countdown the button will update its text to "SENT." If the button is pressed during the countdown (onTick), it will cancel the countdown. I would like to know how to make it revert to the "Push Me" state, and basically allow it to be pressed again and begin a new countdown. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you should not have a new onClickListener inside of the timer because that uses a lot more memory then is needed, and may cause unexpected results. Instead I would suggest using a boolean value for if the timer is on, and use your existing button's onClickListener. Make sure that your timer is declared globally if you are using this. Here is an example of how that might work:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener {
        if(timerIsOn){
          if(timer != null){
            timer.cancel();
            timerIsOn = false;
          }
        }
        else{
        timerIsOn = true;
        //start the timer and do whatever else
        }
    }
```

Comment: But I must check for a click on the same button during the countdown. I think what you have provided will help, but won't I still need that listener inside the timer to check to see if it's been clicked during the countdown?

Comment: The way that onClickListeners work, if at ANY time the view is pressed, it sends the request to the onClick method. The hope in using a boolean value is to understand what to do when it is pressed. If the button is pressed during the countdown then the boolean will be true and therefor it will do the logic you want during the countdown. Otherwise it will function normally